# jasper report server OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space error

Tags: java, tomcat7, out-of-memory, jasperserver

We are trying to setup Jasper report on Ubuntu server.

java version is 1.7.0_79

Tomcat version is -7.0.67

When we start the tomcat server and try to access the home page for the jasper server,

we get the below exception

> Handler processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

I tried changing the JVM parameters, but still it didn't work.

I tried changing the size of Permgen also

here are the contents of `setenv.sh` file

```
EXPORT JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=3072m -Xss2m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```

Comment: I would suggest to run a profiler (e.g. jvisualvm) and check what is happening with permgen when you try to access the page. I'll show also that java options were applied or not.

Comment: what is the estimated file size do you want to generate ??

Answer (score 0):

It may be occur due to generate huge pdf file.
you can use `JRFileVirtualizer`

```
JRFileVirtualizer virtualizer = new JRFileVirtualizer(REPORT_CHUNK_SIZE,tempReportPath);
parameters.put(JRParameter.REPORT_VIRTUALIZER,virtualizer);
```

here `REPORT_CHUNK_SIZE` refers that how many pages you want to chunk over full record and `tempReportPath` refers your fileSystem location where jasper generate temp file and at the end merge the chunk and flush.

the whole operation occur in filesystem so no memory leak happens, if your server can handle huge response then also the report generated.additional time may be required.

Comment: we haven't yet started generating the PDF files, etc. While loading the  login page, this issue happens.